# Convert List<int> to string and vice versa?

Tags: c#

I've looked for hours and can't find an easy way to do this. I have a list of integers, and need to store it as a string so I can post it to an SQL server. Then I need to convert it back from a string to a list of integers later. What is the simplest way to do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> "Use the force, Linq!" - Obi Enum Kenobi

```
using System.Linq;

List<Int32> numbers = new List<Int32>()
{
    1,
    2,
    3,
    4
};

String asString = String
    .Join(
        ", ",
        numbers.Select( n => n.ToString( CultureInfo.InvariantCulture ) )
    );

List<Int32> fromString = asString
    .Split( "," )
    .Select( c => Int32.Parse( c, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture ) );
```

When converting to and from strings that are read by machines, not humans, it's important to avoid using `ToString` and `Parse` without using `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` to ensure consistent formatting regardless of a user's culture and formatting settings.

FWIW, I have my own helper library that adds this useful extension method:

```
public static String ToStringInvariant<T>( this T value )
    where T : IConvertible
{
    return value.ToString( c, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture );
}

public static String StringJoin( this IEnumerable<String> source, String separator )
{
    return String.Join( separator, source );
}
```

Which tidies things up somewhat:

```
String asString = numbers
    .Select( n => n.ToStringInvariant() )
    .StringJoin( ", " );

List<Int32> fromString = asString
    .Split( "," )
    .Select( c => Int32.Parse( c, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture ) );
```

Answer (score 1):

String is the 2nd worst format you can have. Only binary is slightly worse. If you got an Int, keep it an int. Do not transform anything into a string unless you **really** need to (like sending it via XML, use IO). This does not seem like such a case.

The only reason I can think you want to turn them into strings to build a DB query. But do not build SQL Queries via string concatenation. You only get [SQL Injections](https://xkcd.com/327/) doing that. Use SQL Parameters. If you do, there is no need to convert them to string. Something between the SQL Classes and the DBMS will deal with getting it transferred reliably.

If for some reason the SQL is actually storing that Data as NVARCHARS: Replace that DB design. There is no reason to ever have a DB store a number as string. It has proper Number Field Types in anything this side of MS Access.

Comment: Thank you for the information. So none of what I'm doing involves user inputted data. I'm trying to make sure that when a user logs into my app that they get randomly generated numbers that never, ever repeat. So my idea was to generate a list of numbers, randomize the order, store it as a string, and send it to an sql table when the user is first created.
Then I'm going to continually update the sql table with a variable storing the current position in the list to keep track of which numbers have already been stored and how many are left.
Is there a better way to do that?

Comment: @Jessica: You mean you want soemthing like a session ID or user ID? Or a GUID? Generation of such numebrs is best left to the DBMS itself. You can use Autovalues. And then use the INSERT/OUTPUT Syntax to get the data out the moment you inserted it. Putting such a operation into the Application will only get you into race conditions. Also please specify why you are doing that? Because you might be stuck on a XY-Problem.

Comment: I'm creating a quiz, but don't want the questions to repeat. If I'm making this too complicated and there's an easier way I would be open to alternatives, but I've only been programming C# for a month, and I'm also very new to SQL/PHP so I felt more comfortable doing it in C#. If it's safer to do it in the database I'll do that though, but I'll need to do more learning to figure out how to do so because I don't know how to use Autovalues.
Can you recommend a good place to learn more about what you're talking about, whether a book or course or website? It's just beyond my skill level.

Comment: @Jessica: Quizzes a few steps beyond beginners. Usually you need a Question/Player or Question/Game table, that contains foreign keys and stuffs like a result.

Comment: Thank you. I already have the quiz fully functional, the only step I have left is to keep the questions from repeating. I've tried using foreign keys in my SQL database but I'm not really comfortable changing the settings in phpMyAdmin, so instead I have the SQL script insert the data into two different tables with the same primary key, and then pull data from each table as needed.
I know pretty much everything is beyond my level right now, but the easiest way for me to learn is to do it. So I spend a long time figuring out how to do one thing, then later I optimize the code as I learn more.

Comment: @Jessica: "I already have the quiz fully functional, the only step I have left is to keep the questions from repeating." And that is usually one of the first things you have to deal with, because that informs more about your design then any minor stuff like the UI.

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way is to make a new list each time and casting each item as you iterate.